# how to hook d3d to load custom texture about dds file to replace the application's dds file

Tags: c++, hook, direct3d

I have use d3d9 to write a d3d demo and it load a texture file(1.dds). now I want to load the custom texture file(2.dds) to replace 1.dds by hook d3d. I have search many articles but I can't realized the functional. That would be grate if anyone can solve this.

Comment: How about just load 2.dds and write its pointer to the address which hold 1.dds IDirect3DTexture9*?

Comment: But i can't find out the 1.dds address. how can i find out witch address is 1.dds IDirect3DTexture9*? what's the d3d9 function need to be hooked? i have try to hook the setTexture. but it seem not work.

Comment: how did you hook the SetTexture function? You need to lookup IDirect3DDevice9 vtable at index 65 (SetTexture) to find its address, if you have done that, then it might use an effect in which textures are set by the ID3DXBaseEffect::SetTexture method

Comment: Another approach is to side-load the d3d9.dll or d3dx9.dll to inject your DLL early on and hook D3DXCreateTextureFromFile or something else that the game uses to load textures